# arecord wav file size limit with named pipes

Tags: audio

Scenario:

OS: raspbian buster

1. I have an audio chain as follows *USB Audio Input->arecord->named
   pipe->forked-daapd*.   In the present configuration, *arecord* and
   *forked-daapd* are both set up as standard *systemd* services.
2. The goal is to send audio from a turntable to a network audio
   endpoint (Sonos).
3. The arecord part of the pipe is a very simple "***arecord -D
   plughw:1,0 -t wav -f cd /srv/music/phono-source***"
4. If I create the named pipe ("phono-source") with mkfifo and then
   launch the *arecord* and *forked-daap* services, everything appears to
   work as expected.
5. If I leave the configuration running but "idle", ie turntable not in
   use, so assume effectively generating silence/noise, at some point
   later, the original named pipe object gets renamed to
   "phono-source-01" and a new conventional (not pipe) file
   "phono-source-02" gets created. arecord is now writing data to the
   new file, which grows in size at the expected rate.
6. This had me baffled for a little while until I realized that the
   audio out would have reached the maximum size for a wav file.
   Leaving things running for a little while longer, this was sort of
   confirmed as when phono-source-02 reached 2147483692 bytes, output
   resumed to a new conventional file, phono-source-03.
7. I was vaguely aware of a 2Gig limit on wav files, but I had assumed
   that was a physical file limit, and since I am writing to a pipe in
   this case that it would not apply - apparently not. The brute force
   approach here would be to terminate the arecord service after each
   album was played on the turntable and start it for the beginning of
   a new album.

Any suggestions on a strategy for avoiding this problem, either by doing something different with the pipe, or using an alternate audio grabber like sox?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code for [aplay.c/arecord.c](https://github.com/certik/record/blob/master/arecord.c), you'll see a table for formats like

```
static const struct fmt_capture {
    void (*start) (int fd, size_t count);
    void (*end) (int fd);
    char *what;
    long long max_filesize;
} fmt_rec_table[] = {
    {   NULL,       NULL,       N_("raw data"),     LLONG_MAX },
    {   begin_voc,  end_voc,    N_("VOC"),      16000000LL },
    /* FIXME: can WAV handle exactly 2GB or less than it? */
    {   begin_wave, end_wave,   N_("WAVE"),     2147483648LL },
    {   begin_au,   end_au,     N_("Sparc Audio"),  LLONG_MAX }
};
```

So you can see that WAV file size is restricted by design.

You may have more luck with `-t raw` (might need additional parameters for sample rate etc.) or `-t au` (Sun Sparc Audio file format), assuming `forked-daapd` can handle those (I've never used `forked-daapd`). LLONG_MAX is 9223372036854775807 on a 64-bit system, probably your file system complains before the file reaches that size.

If you do need WAV files, keep in mind that this format it has a header with the file size which can't be larger than 2 GB, so probably most implementations will have some kind of restriction wrt. max file size.

I don't know any particular implementation of an audio recorder that has a "streaming mode" (which actually would violate the WAV spec, to my knowledge) and ignores this on purpose. Which doesn't mean it doesn't exist.